# Problema de llave foránea en pagina conectada con phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, modelorelacional

Estoy haciendo una página en PHP, la cual conecto con phpmyadmin en la cual tengo una base de datos con 2 tablas: `datos_personales` y `reserva`

En la tabla `datos_personales` tengo una columna llamada `ID`, la cual incluí como llave foránea en la otra tabla. El problema es que al momento de intentar agregar datos desde el formulario me marca el error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a
> child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`prueba`.`reserva`,
> CONSTRAINT `fk_reserva_datos_personales` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_person`)
> REFERENCES `datos_personales` (`ID`)) in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bdM4S2\index2.php:67 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bdM4S2\index2.php(67): mysqli->query('INSERT INTO
> res...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bdM4S2\index2.php on line
> 67

El código es el siguiente:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Reservas BD</title>
</head>
    <body style="background-color:#32E0C4">

   <center><h1>Reservas</h1>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        
        Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"><br><br>
        telefono: <input type="text" name="telefono"><br><br>
        Fecha y hora:  <input type="date" name="Fecha_hora"><br><br><br>
        Cantidad de personas: <input type="int" name="Cantidad"><br><br>
        Ocasion:<input type="text" name="Ocasion"><br><br>
        Especificaciones: <input type="text" name="Especificaciones"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="insertar" value="Enviar Datos">
    </form>

    <?php
    // Verificar si se ha enviado el formulario
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['insertar'])) {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $database = "prueba";

        // Crear la conexión
$password = "";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, 'root', '', $database);


        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Error de conexión: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // Obtener datos del formulario
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $Fecha_hora = $_POST['Fecha_hora'];
        $Cantidad = $_POST['Cantidad']; 
        $Ocasion = $_POST['Ocasion'];  
        $Especificaciones = $_POST['Especificaciones'];

        // Insertar datos en la base de datos
        $sql = "INSERT INTO datos_personales (nombre, telefono) VALUES ('$nombre', '$telefono')";


        $sql2 =  "INSERT INTO reserva (Fecha_hora, Cantidad_personas, Especificaciones, Ocasion_especial) VALUES ('$Fecha_hora', '$Cantidad', '$Especificaciones', '$Ocasion')";

//Calculos
$cost_tot = 1500 + (($Cantidad-2)*150);          




        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Datos envíados correctamente";
        } else {
            echo "Error al insertar datos: " . $conn->error;
        }


        if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
            echo "Datos envíados correctamente";
        } else {
            echo "Error al insertar datos: " . $conn->error;
        }



        $conn->close();
    }
    ?></center> 

</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. Revisa lo que planteas; en la imagen se nota **SELECT ... 'reserva'** luego de un resultado (asumo debe ser resultado del `SELECT`) pero acorde a tu código PHP parece más ser de `datos_personales`. El error se genera en el `INSERT INTO reserva` pero en tu sentencia no se observa incluyas el nuevo o existente valor `ID` con el que está relacionado que debe ser `reserva.ID_person`.

Comment: Obvio va a dar el error porque en `$sql2` no estás incluyendo a `ID_person`. Ese ID es calculado auto-incrementalmente al insertar `$sql1`. Para encontrar el `ID`, hay varias formas, (1) puede ser con [mysql::insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) (recomendado), (2) haciendo un `SELECT ID FROM datos_personales ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1`, (3) en 2 pasos: primero creando al usuario y luego desde otro formulario seleccionar el usuario creado y hacer el INSERT con la reserva.

Comment: Una disculpa, apenas estoy estudiando este tema y no termino de comprender las cosas

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer que funcione, pero el principal problema es ¿qué pasa si quisieras tener registros en el tiempo de los usuarios y por ejemplo, uno ya registrado quiere hacer otra reserva? No se puede porque siempre tienes 2 `INSERT`. Entonces siempre tendrás muchos usuarios con una sola reserva, por lo cual tu base de datos no servirá para hacer reportes.
A menos que lo anterior no te importe y solo quieres tener el registro de las reservas.

Para que este código funcione, tienes que (1) asegurarte que el primer `INSERT` se hizo correctamente y (2) si lo anterior es verdadero, entonces extraer el ID insertado y usarlo en la segunda consulta.

En tu código, elimina `$sql2` en donde lo tienes y las 2 estructuras `if/else` cámbialas a esta otra forma:

```php
        // ...
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Cliente insertado correctamente";
            $id_insertado = $conn->insert_id; // Este es el ID Insertado
            $sql2 =  "INSERT INTO reserva 
                (ID_person, Fecha_hora, Cantidad_personas, Especificaciones, Ocasion_especial) 
                VALUES ('$id_insertado', '$Fecha_hora', '$Cantidad', '$Especificaciones', '$Ocasion')";
            if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
                echo "Reserva creada correctamente";
            } else {
                echo "Error al insertar la reserva: " . $conn->error;
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error al insertar el usuario: " . $conn->error;
        }
        // ...
```